# "for the right syntax to use near '0' at line 1" in Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Very weird bug taking place. I have a stored procedure that works fine on the Live Server (MySQL v. 5.5.12) but on local (v. 5.5.25a) I get an error. Here's the Stored Procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `SaveIDForTable`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SaveIDForTable`(IN OffID varchar(100),IN TabName VARCHAR(255))
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
set @sql='create table if not exists '||TabName||'(ID bigint(20) NOT NULL,exp date not null,PRIMARY KEY (ID))';
PREPARE statment FROM @sql;
EXECUTE statment;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE statment;
set @sql='insert ignore into '||TabName||' select ID,curdate() from all_data where Official_ID=\''||OffID||'\'';
PREPARE statment FROM @sql;
EXECUTE statment;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE statment;
END$$
```

But When I run the Stored Procedure

```
CALL SaveIDForTable ('203200702000000-207-5C2FF0','testTable')
```

I get the error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0' at line 1
```

I've tried running other stored procs on my local machine and they  work fine, but this one for some reason I can't get to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In `INSERT` statement, there's no whitespace before `TabName`, which will be an error, but I don't think it is this error.  `SELECT @sql` instead of executing it to see what the statement looks like with concatenations in place.

Comment: you should use SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE SaveIDForTable to see if the code is the same as you expect to be.

Comment: actually, there is the proper white space, I had to modify the name of the table to post here and deleted the white space. As far as the Select SQL. It doesn't work, because I still get the same error from before.

Comment: @Sebas I tried that as well, and everything looks the same.

Comment: it is probably a software version problem.see the version in server and try to put that version in your local

Comment: Is `PIPES_AS_CONCAT` your `sql_mode`?

Comment: Tried that, still same problem

Comment: Thank You @Wrikken! That was it. I was beginning to think it was hopeless. The import I had run had switched SQL Modes and switching them back fixed it. Can you post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the correct answer.